# Add an ArrayList<Boolean> to an Android Intent

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to add an `ArrayList<Boolean>` to an intent in Android and then retrieve it.

[There are methods to add and retrieve Integer, String, etc. ArrayLists to and from intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), but I don't see any for an `ArrayList<Boolean>`. For now, I'm having to convert my `ArrayList<Boolean>` to a `boolean[]`, add it to the intent, and then convert it back to an `ArrayList<Boolean>` when I retrieve it from the intent.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: ArrayList<Boolean> is serializable: You could use that but you will still have to cast when you receive the intent on the other end.

Comment: As an optional, Arrays.asList is a built-in method convert Arrays[] to ArrayList. You can use it to convert back to ArrayList

Comment: @edisonthk For sure. However, for this question, I'm not focused on the how behind the conversion, but the ability to avoid converting all together if possible. I also find it interesting that there are methods that can be used with other primitive wrapper types, just not with Boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `putExtra(...)` on your intent, and throw in your ArrayList. When retrieving, cast the returned value from the `getSerializableExtra` method call to `ArrayList<Boolean>`.

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, java.io.Serializable)

Comment: For clarity, I would say `getSerializableExtra` instead of `getExtra`.

Comment: Definitely! Thanks for the comment, Jeff.